# Highcharts Gauge misplaced labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts solid gauge with decimal value. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7hm1mkbn/

```
$('#container-temp').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 10.39,
        max: 23.83,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: [23.23],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">C</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' C'
        }
    }]

}));
```

The min-max labels are misplaced. Any suggestion?

Comment: Removing `tickPixelInterval: 400`?

Comment: labels remain misplaced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want min and max ticks (with labels) you can replace your `tickPixelInterval` with a static definition of `tickPositions`. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hm1mkbn/1/)):

```
yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [10.39, 23.83]
}
```

If you may want more ticks (and labels) you may want to make a more dynamic function using `tickPositioner`. For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hm1mkbn/3/)):

```
yAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function () {
        var positions = [],
            numberOfTicks = 5;
            tick = this.min,
            increment = (this.max - this.min) / (numberOfTicks - 1);

        for (tick; tick - increment <= this.max; tick += increment) {
            positions.push(Math.round(tick * 100) / 100);
        }
        return positions;
    }
}
```